# Add new service metrics to prometheus-operator

Tags: kubernetes, microservices, prometheus, kubernetes-helm, prometheus-operator

I'm deploying Prometheus-operator to my cluster by Helm chart but I implement a custom service to monitor my application, I need to add my service to Prometheus-operator to see my metrics data.

How I can do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At first, you need to deploy Prometheus-operator by Helm or manually:

```sh
# By Helm:
$ helm install stable/prometheus-operator --generate-name
 
# By manual: for release `release-0.41`
kubectl apply -f  https://raw.githubusercontent.com/prometheus-operator/prometheus-operator/release-0.41/bundle.yaml
```

If your cluster is RBAC enabled then you need to install RBAC stuff for `Prometheus` object:

```sh
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: prometheus
rules:
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources:
  - nodes
  - nodes/metrics
  - services
  - endpoints
  - pods
  verbs: ["get", "list", "watch"]
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources:
  - configmaps
  verbs: ["get"]
- nonResourceURLs: ["/metrics"]
  verbs: ["get"]
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: prometheus
  namespace: default
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: prometheus
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: prometheus
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: prometheus
  namespace: default
```

Then you need to deploy `Promethues` object:

```sh
apiVersion: monitoring.coreos.com/v1
kind: Prometheus
metadata:
  name: prometheus
  labels:
    prometheus: prometheus
spec:
  replicas: 1
  serviceAccountName: prometheus
  serviceMonitorSelector:
    matchLabels:
      k8s-app: prometheus
  serviceMonitorNamespaceSelector:
    matchLabels:
      prometheus: prometheus
  resources:
    requests:
      memory: 400Mi
```

Here, `Prometheus` object will select all `ServiceMonitor` that meet up the below conditions:

- `ServiceMonitor` will have the `k8s-app: prometheus` label.
- `ServiceMonitor` will be created in that namespaces which have `prometheus: prometheus` label.

The ServiceMonitor has a label selector to select Services and their underlying Endpoint objects. The Service object for the example application selects the Pods by the `app` label having the `example-app` value. The Service object also specifies the port on which the metrics are exposed.

```sh
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: example-app
  labels:
    app: example-app
spec:
  selector:
    app: example-app
  ports:
  - name: web
    port: 8080
```

This Service object is discovered by a ServiceMonitor, which selects in the same way. The `app` label must have the value `example-app`.

```sh
apiVersion: monitoring.coreos.com/v1
kind: ServiceMonitor
metadata:
  name: example-app
  labels:
    k8s-app: prometheus
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: example-app
  namespaceSelector:
    # matchNames:
    # - demo
    any: true
  endpoints:
  - port: web
```

Here, `namespaceSelector` is used to select all-namespaces where the service is created. you can specify specific any namespace using `matchNames`.

You can also create a `ServiceMonitor` in any namespace as you want. But you need to specify it in `Prometheus` cr's `spec`, like:

```sh
  serviceMonitorNamespaceSelector:
    matchLabels:
      prometheus: prometheus
```

The above `serviceMonitorNamespaceSelector` is used in `Prometheus` operator to select that namespace which has the label `prometheus: prometheus`. Suppose you have a namespace `demo` and in this `demo` namespace you have created a `Prometheus` then you need to add label `prometheus: prometheus` in `demo` namespace using patch:

```sh
$ kubectl patch namespace demo -p '{"metadata":{"labels": {"prometheus":"prometheus"}}}'
```

You can find more details here:

- Helm: https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/prometheus-operator
- Manual: https://github.com/prometheus-operator/prometheus-operator/blob/release-0.41/Documentation/user-guides/getting-started.md
- namespaceSelector: https://github.com/prometheus-operator/prometheus-operator/blob/master/Documentation/design.md

Comment: thanks, if I have Prometheus on the different namespace
and my service on the default namespace 
what I do change?

Comment: I have updated my answer and added a new reference. you maybe find your answer from the above answer.

Comment: thanks 
but now after applying your solution Prometheus Service Discovery get 
>>>monitoring/sg-prometheus-rabbitmq-exporter/0 (0/16 active targets) -- this is my service

and  the  data does not show on Prometheus

Comment: my service is 
Selector:          app=prometheus-rabbitmq-exporter,release=sg-prometheus-rabbitmq-exporter
Type:              ClusterIP
IP:                10.3.144.40
Port:              rabbitmq-exporter  9419/TCP
TargetPort:        publish/TCP
Endpoints:         10.2.0.47:9419
Session Affinity:  None

Comment: + my ServiceMonitor is 
apiVersion: monitoring.coreos.com/v1
kind: ServiceMonitor
metadata:
  name: sg-prometheus-rabbitmq-exporter
  labels:
    k8s-app: prometheus
    release: sg-prometheus-operator
spec:
  endpoints:
  - path: /metrics
    port: web
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: prometheus-rabbitmq-exporter
      release: sg-prometheus-rabbitmq-exporter

Comment: 1st, your app must have the labels: `app=prometheus-rabbitmq-exporter,release=sg-prometheus-rabbitmq-exporter`. What's your service `labels`? from your `ServiceMonitor` info it will be `app: prometheus-rabbitmq-exporter, release: sg-prometheus-rabbitmq-exporter`.

Comment: but 
waseem@wawashra:~/k8s$ kubectl describe pod sg-prometheus-rabbitmq-exporter-cff458465-lkkq9 -n monitoring
Name:         sg-prometheus-rabbitmq-exporter-cff458465-lkkq9
Namespace:    monitoring
Priority:     0
Node:         ci-node-1/51.178.95.248
Start Time:   Thu, 27 Aug 2020 14:05:04 +0300
Labels:       app=prometheus-rabbitmq-exporter
              pod-template-hash=cff458465
              release=sg-prometheus-rabbitmq-exporter

and does not work :/