# Seldon: How to Use My Own Grafana and Prometheus Instances?

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, grafana, seldon, seldon-core

I want to use my already existing Prometheus and Grafana instances in the monitoring namespace to emulate what [`seldon-core-analytics`](https://github.com/SeldonIO/seldon-core/tree/master/helm-charts/seldon-core-analytics) is doing. I'm using the prometheus community helm charts and installed `kube-prometheus-stack`  on k8s. Here's what I've done so far:

In the `values.yaml` file, under the prometheus config, I added the following annotations:

```
annotations:
  prometheus.io/scrape: "true"
  prometheus.io/path: "/prometheus
```

Next, I looked at the `prometheus-config.yaml` in their Github repo  and copied and pasted the configuration in a configmap file.

Also, created a ServiceMonitor

```
apiVersion: monitoring.coreos.com/v1
kind: ServiceMonitor
metadata:
  name: seldon-servicemonitor-default
  labels:
    seldon-monitor: seldon-default
  namespace: monitoring
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: seldon-core
  endpoints:
    - interval: 15s
      path: /metrics
      port: http
    - interval: 15s
      path: /prometheus
      port: http
  namespaceSelector:
    matchNames:
      - seldon
      - default
      - monitoring
```

No errors with the above steps so far, but it doesn't appear as though the prometheus instance is able to scrape the metrics from a model I deployed on a different namespace. What other configuration do I need to do so that my own Prometheus and Grafana instances can gather and visualize the metrics from my seldon deployed models? The documentation doesn't really explain how to do this on your own instances, and the one they provide to you through `seldon-core-analytics` isn't production-ready.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prometheus configuration in `seldon-core-analytics` is quite standard. It is based on built-in Kubernetes service discovery and it uses annotations to find scraping targets:

```yaml
annotations:
  prometheus.io/scrape: true
  prometheus.io/path: /metrics
  prometheus.io/scheme: http
  prometheus.io/port: 9100
```

In [their example configuration](https://github.com/SeldonIO/seldon-core/blob/master/helm-charts/seldon-core-operator/values.yaml) prometheus will target pods, services, and endpoints with `prometheus.io/scrape: true` annotation on them. The other three labels are used to override default scraping parameters per target. Thus if you have a config as in the example, you only need to put some of these annotations on pods.

The way `kube-prometheus-stack` works is different. It uses [prometheus operator](https://github.com/prometheus-operator/prometheus-operator) and CRDs to shape the configuration. [This](https://github.com/prometheus-operator/prometheus-operator/blob/master/Documentation/design.md) design document describes purpose of each CRD.

You need to create a `ServiceMonitor` resource in order to define a scraping rule for new services. `ServiceMonitor` itself should have labels as defined in prometheus resource (another CRD) under `serviceMonitorSelector` key. It is hard to provide you with a working example in these circumstances but [this](https://github.com/prometheus-operator/prometheus-operator/blob/master/Documentation/user-guides/getting-started.md#related-resources) short guide should be enough to understand what to do.

I suggest you describe one of the `ServiceMonitor`s that you have, then create a new one changing labels under `matchLabels`. Do not change the namespace in a new object, prometheus operator does not look for `ServiceMonitor`s in other namespaces by default. To make `ServiceMonitor` discover targets in all namespaces the `namespaceSelector` has to be empty:

```yaml
spec:
  namespaceSelector:
    any: true
```

Comment: Thanks @anemyte. The references you provided I've look through already. I tried with a service monitor but still wasn't scraping the seldon deployments as targets. I have edited my original comment with the service monitor file.

Comment: @RileyHun Seems legit. What have you checked so far? Prometheus configuration/targets in the web UI? is there anything related to seldon?. Prometheus operator logs may have some valuable information if there is a problem with CRD. Finally, some CRDs (not sure about these in particular) may show some hints in their status (available with kubectl describe).

Comment: @aneymyte - I've only checked the Prometheus UI and looked at the targets under status. Maybe it has something do with RBAC authorization? 

Looking through this article: https://medium.com/kubernetes-tutorials/simple-management-of-prometheus-monitoring-pipeline-with-the-prometheus-operator-b445da0e0d1a

Comment: @RileyHun I see RBAC roles and bindings are defined in the helm chart but I can't tell what's in your cluster :) . I suggest you delete and create ServiceMonitor again. While doing so capture logs of both prometheus and the operator. There can be something about the CRD, maybe an error or a warning. Also, check prometheus configuration in the UI. It is available under 'status'. Can you see there something related to seldon or its ServiceMonitor? At last, just to be sure, do you have a Service object for your seldon model?

Comment: Yes there is a Service object for the seldon model. RBAC roles are already defined? I missed that. I was going to create another one. Already deleted my ServiceMonitor.

Comment: Now all my targets disappeared after I created a new ServiceMonitor. I was following the instructions from this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63606347/add-new-service-metrics-to-prometheus-operator

Comment: I got Prometheus connecting to a generic app. Although, all the other targets disappeared. I am not sure what happened there. Maybe I replaced the default ServiceMonitor that was scraping the monitoring namespace?

Comment: @RileyHun Its possible but there are many things that can go wrong. How many ServiceMonitors are there? `kubectl get servicemonitors -n monitoring` If there is only one, then it seems you did replace it.

Answer (score 1):

ServiceMonitors are extremely difficult to debug.
My debugging strategy would be to:-

1. **Check if the ServiceMonitor created is being read by the Prometheus**:-
   Look at the /targets URL. (There should be a target in 0/0
   state at least) If not, that means the ServiceMonitor itself is not being picked up by Prometheus.I suggest looking into the following configuration in
   your kube-prometheus-stack configuration.

   ```
       serviceMonitorSelectorNilUsesHelmValues: false
       serviceMonitorSelector: {}
       serviceMonitorNamespaceSelector: {}
   ```

   The default ServiceMonitor has the Helm metadata attached to it
   which is used by the Prometheus Operator to filter/choose the
   ServiceMonitors to monitor. Setting
   `serviceMonitorSelectorNilUsesHelmValues:false` will ignore any such
   selection.
2. **If the ServiceMonitor is visible in targets but there are no targets.**:-
   In this case the issue lies between the ServiceMonitor and
   the pods it is trying to scrape.Check if the ports you mentioned are
   accessible and the pods fulfill the selectors mentioned.

My advice would be to start another dummy ServiceMonitor by following [this](https://sysdig.com/blog/kubernetes-monitoring-prometheus-operator-part3/) and then modifying the ServiceMonitor one step at a time till it starts monitoring the `seldon-core-analytics` pods