# How to scrape metrics from other services using Prometheus merviceMonitors

Tags: rabbitmq, prometheus, kubernetes-helm

I would like to learn, how to add new metrics to my Prometheus instance. I would like to use Helm chart `bitnami/rabbitmq` ([link](https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/bitnami/rabbitmq)) in version `12.14.0`. Deployed in namespace `utils`.

I have Prometheus running using Helm chart `prometheus-community/kube-prometheus-stack` ([link](https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/prometheus-community/kube-prometheus-stack)) version `56.7.0`. Deployed in namespace `kube-prometheus-stack`.

My idea was enabling `serviceMonitor` by adjusting rabbitmq `values.yml`. However even though `serviceMonitor` resource was created, I cannot see it under **Prometheus Service Discovery**.

What am I doing wrong and what should be fixed?

Is it required to configure prometheus somehow?

#### Rabbitmq `values.yml`

```yaml
metrics:
  enabled: true

  serviceMonitor:
    enabled: true
```

#### Prometheus `values.yml`

```yaml
# Configure Prometheus
prometheus:
  # Set custom labels for identification
  prometheusSpec:
    # Monitor all namespaces
    serviceMonitorNamespaceSelector: {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I was constantly working on this issue, as usual, and thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63609629/12193952) answer, I was able to figure things out.

Solution is:

#### Step 1

I had loaded prometheus resource definition in yaml

```
k get prometheus kube-prometheus-stack-prometheus -oyaml
```

And I wanted to check this part configuration. It tells which resources should be monitored by Prometheus. By default, this is set  `podMonitorSelector: {}` in `values.yml`, so I did not care about that.

```yaml
podMonitorSelector:
    matchLabels:
      release: kube-prometheus-stack
```

#### Step 2

Add found labels to rabbitmq serviceMonitor

```yaml
metrics:
  enabled: true

  serviceMonitor:
    enabled: true
    labels:
      release: kube-prometheus-stack
```